# Order of evaluation compound procedures metacircular 'apply'

Tags: scheme, evaluation, sicp, mit-scheme, order-of-execution

I'm studying [SICP chapter 4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%25_sec_4.1.1) and its implementation of a metacircular Scheme evaluator. I'm having difficulties understanding how user defined procedures are handled by its `apply` procedure.

The metacircular evaluator is  composed of two main procedures: `eval` and `apply`. The basic idea is to recursively apply `eval` until there's only self-evaluating expressions (like numbers and strings) or expressions with primitive procedures that can be handled directly by `apply`.

The evaluator works following the [environment model of evaluation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%25_sec_3.2), where we bind variables to their associated values and create new frames every time `lambda` is invoked. Procedure definitions are handled this way. The procedure name is binded in the environment and when it's called, its body is evaluated in a new frame where the parameters have been binded to the arguments used to call it.

This specific part is reflected in the following lines of the `apply` procedure:

```
(define (apply procedure arguments)
  (cond (...)
        ((compound-procedure? procedure)
         (eval-sequence
           (procedure-body procedure)
           (extend-environment
             (procedure-parameters procedure)
             arguments
             (procedure-environment procedure))))
        (...)
```

An user defined procedure is recognized by the `compound-procedure?` predicate. The `eval-sequence` procedure just evaluates `(procedure-body procedure)` and `(extend-environment ...)` sequentially and returns the value of the last expression.

**My problem is** that, as I understand it, *we should extend the environment first* and *only then* evaluate the body of the procedure:

```
         (eval-sequence
           (extend-environment
             (procedure-parameters procedure)
             arguments
             (procedure-environment procedure))
           (procedure-body procedure))
```

For example in:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(square 5)
```

The first line will bind `square` to a lambda (with its associated parameters and body). This binding will be recognized in the second line. Then I understand we create a new frame where `x = 5` and only then is the body of square executed. But this order seems to be inverted by the `apply` procedure, where the body of the procedure is evaluated before binding the parameters to the arguments.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me understand this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(procedure-body procedure)` does not evaluate the body of the `procedure`, it simply returns it.

The body of the procedure is evaluated by `eval-sequence`. It receives the new environment as its second argument, and that environment is created by `extend-environment`, which adds all the parameter bindings to the environment.

Then `eval-sequence` evaluates the procedure body in the scope of that extended environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I overlooked that `eval-sequence` accepted an environment as a second parameter, provided by `extend-environment` in this case.